# ng-model is not bind with controller's $scope when I am creating a form dynamically using directive.

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

view code:- mydir is my custom directive

```
<div ng-model="vdmodel" mydir="dataValue">                                  

</div>
```

my directive :-

```
app.directive('mydir',['$translate',function($translate){



 return {
            restrict: 'A',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {dir:'=mydir'},
            compile: function(element, attrs) {
                return function(scope, element, attrs, controller){
                    var setTemplate = '';
                    var setOpt = '';                    

                    if(scope.dir.itemtype== 'NUMBER'){




                        setTemplate = '<input type="number" class="form-control form-font ng-animate ng-dirty"';
                        setTemplate +='" ng-model="dir[somevalue]" value="'+scope.sizing.somevalue+'" >';
                        element.html(setTemplate);
                    }
    }
  }
 }
});
```

There are many more form element in directive, but when I am trying to submit and collect value in my controller function I get nothing. 
What I am doing wrong and what is the best way to collect form values ?

Comment: What exactly are you going to achive? Build a form dynamically from a model?

Comment: I am getting json data in my controller, which contains long array and tells what type of dom element Should be created based on "type" I am sending this information to "mydir" directive and creating elements dynamically but when I am submitting form I can't collect form data in my controller.

Comment: What is the use of `vdmodel`? In directive, you bind input with `dir.somevalue` and `dir` is binded with `dataValue` in controller, so the input will eventually be binded with `dataValue.somevalue`. I couldn't see `vdmodel` use anywhere.

Comment: this doesn't work even when I had removed vdmodel

Answer (score 0):

there are quiet a few changes that you will need to do

1.as you are using isolate scope, pass ngModel as well to the directive

`scope: {dir:'=mydir', ngModel: '='},`

2.as per the best practise ngModel must always have a dot

`ng-model="params.vdmodel"`

3.make sure to initialize the params object in controller

`$scope.params = {}`

Comment: this doesn't work for me, can you please point me to some good examples?

Comment: answer from @TheRodeo is much detailed one... also have a look at egghead.io video.. a must watch for angularjs beginner

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a directive would share the same scope as the parent controller but since you are defining a scope in your directive, it sets up it's own isolate scope. Now since the controller and directive have their seperate scope, you need a way to share the data between them which is now done by using data: "=" in scope.

The app code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.vdmodel = {};
})
    .directive("mydir", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope:{
            data:"=model",
            dir:'=mydir'
        },
        templateUrl: 'test/form.html'
    };
    });
```

The form.html

```
<form>
        Name : <input type="text" ng-model="data.modelName" /><br><br>
        Age : <input type="number" ng-model="data.modelAge" /><br><br>
        Place : <input type="text" ng-model="data.modelPlace" /><br><br>
        Gender: 
                <input type="radio" ng-model="data.modelGender" value="male"/>Male<br> 
                <input type="radio" ng-model="data.modelGender" value="female"/>Female<br><br><br>
</form>
```

The page.html

```
<div ng-app="myApp" >
    <div ng-controller="myController" >
        <div model="vdmodel" mydir="dataValue"></div>

        <h3>Display:</h3> 
        <div>
            <div>Name : {{myData.modelName}} </div><br>
            <div>Age : {{myData.modelAge}}</div><br>
            <div>Place : {{myData.modelPlace}}</div><br>
            <div>Gender : {{myData.modelGender}}</div><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$compile` service to compile a template and link with the current scope before put it into the `element`.

```
.directive('mydir', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      dir: '=mydir'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
      var setTemplate = '';
      var setOpt = '';

      if (scope.dir.itemtype == 'NUMBER') {
        setTemplate = '<input type="number" class="form-control form-font ng-animate ng-dirty"';
        setTemplate += '" ng-model="dir.somevalue" value="' + scope.dir.somevalue + '" >';

        element.html($compile(setTemplate)(scope));
      }
    }
  }
});
```

See the plunker below for the full working example.

**Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/7i9bYmd8blPNHch5jze4?p=preview

Comment: this works fine with simple data, but I have nested objects and "dataValue" is one of the array value inside object, is there a way I can send it to controller without declaration in controller.

Comment: Then, please update your question to include the full detail of what you are trying to achive. What does the nested objects look like? What information do you want to sent to controller?

Comment: Tarm can you please help me on setting selected value here is Plunker:- http://plnkr.co/edit/VA4meqISN20CjqDDDlM0?p=preview

Comment: The plunker site is currently down :(, I will have a look later.